# Would this be the correct way to wire this breakout board sensor with an ADC?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, wiring, breadboard, breakout

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. It is going to be wired to an ADC  called the [MCP3008](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NAY3RB2) like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/analogue/):

[image]

I also have a breakout board, called the [ML8511 UV Sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12705) which I am going to solder to the breadboard.

Could someone explain where to solder the breakout board to the breadboard and which wires should be placed where.

Answer (score 0):

First, the point of the breadboard is so that you don't have to solder.  But you will have to solder hookup wires to the ML8511 -- connect the male ends of those into the breadboard.

The UV sensor needs +3.3V and GND for power.  Connect the EN pin to +3.3V unless you want to be able to put the sensor in sleep mode.  You can probably connect the OUT pin to any of the channels of the ADC -- channel 0 would be typical.

Also you should put a 0.1uF capacitor between VDD and DGND and another between VREF and AGND to reduce noise.

Comment: What do you mean by putting "between VDD and DGND" and between "VREF and AGND"

Comment: I mean acquire two 0.1uF capacitors.  Then connect one between VDD and DGND of the MCP3008, and one between VREF and AGND.

Comment: @Roymunson if this answers your question please click 'Accept Answer.'